# The return type 'void' isn't assignable to 'FutureOr<T>', as required by 'Future.catchError'

Tags: dart

I have some code like this:

`File("foo.txt").readAsString().catchError((e)=>print(e));`

The compiler is complaining
`info: The return type 'void' isn't assignable to 'FutureOr<T>', as required by 'Future.catchError'.`

I can't seem to give it what it wants and can't find a single clear usage example in any of the docs (just a long issue in git about how many ways there are to mis-use this). If I take the docs at face value, I should be able to return a bool, or a future, neither make the analyzer happy.

How do I provide this FutureOr?

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE]. Is there a reason you cannot use a traditional `try`/ `catch` ?

Comment: I can, just trying to understand how this syntax works. This should reproduce:
`File("foo.txt").readAsString().catchError((e)=>print(e));`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[The documentation for `Future.catchError`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Future/catchError.html) could be a lot clearer, but the relevant part is:

> `onError` is called with the error and possibly stack trace, and the returned future is completed with the result of this call in exactly the same way as for `then`'s `onError`.

Cross-referencing to [the documentation for `Future.then`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Future/then.html), the relevant portion is:

> The `onError` callback must return a value or future that can be used to complete the returned future, so it must be something assignable to `FutureOr<R>`.

Since `File.readAsString` returns a `Future<String>`, your `catchError` callback also must return a `Future<String>` (or a `String`).  Examples of doing that:

```dart
File("foo.txt").readAsString().catchError((e) {
  print(e);
  return Future.value('');
});

File("foo.txt").readAsString().catchError((e) async {
  print(e);
  return '';
});
```

Logically, this makes sense; because given:

```dart
String value = await File("foo.txt").readAsString().catchError(...);
```

then if `readAsString` succeeds, `value` should be assigned a `String`.  If it fails, since you catch the exception without rethrowing it, `value` still needs to be assigned a `String`.

Put another way, your code is equivalent to:

```dart
Future<String> readFoo() async {
  try {
    return await File("foo.txt").readAsString();
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
  // Oops, missing return value.
}
```

In general, I strongly recommend using `async`/`await` with `try`-`catch` instead of using `.catchError`, which would avoid this confusion.

Comment: Given `Future<int> f() async => 0;`, you get a warning doing this `f().catchError(print);` but not for doing `f().catchError((_) {});`Why? Let me know if it requires more explanation, I'll ask a separate question and don't forget to use @ when replying :) Thanks

Comment: @iDecode `print` won't work because it's declared to return `void`, but as explained in this answer, it would need to return an `int`.  I don't know why the anonymous function doesn't generate a static analysis error; I suspect it's because the return type is inferred in that case and because it would implicitly return `null`.  If null-safety is enabled, it still doesn't generate a static analysis error (which is possibly a bug), but it will result in a runtime exception when invoked.

Comment: Yes, it should show the static warning (that's why I wrote the comment), I'm on Dart 2.12 (enabled NNBD by setting 2.12 thanks to you), and I'm using pedantic package. Should I create an issue for it, and if yes, where: pedantic, dart-sdk or somewhere else?

Comment: @iDecode dart-sdk would be a good starting point.