# Future.then must return a value of the returned future's type

Tags: flutter, api, dart, exception, dart-null-safety

I'm continuously getting this error

```
Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s) (onError): The error handler of Future.then must return a value of the returned future's type
```

**NetworkApi**

```
class NetworkApi {
  NetworkApi(this.url);

  final String url;

  Future getData() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      String data = response.body;

      return jsonDecode(data);
    } else {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(response.statusCode);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**ApiSelector**

```
class ApiSelector {
  Future getApiData({String categoryName = ""}) async {
    late NetworkApi _api;
    if(categoryName != ""){
     _api = NetworkApi('api');
    }else{
      _api = NetworkApi('myapi');
    }
    var Data = await _api.getData();
    if (Data['status'] == 'error') {
      throw'Error while fetching data';
    }
    return MyModel.fromJson(Data);
  }
}
```

**MyFunction To Call API selector**

```
  Future getDataFromApi() async {
    await _apiSelector
        .getApiData(categoryName: "Some Category")
        .then((value) {
      myModel = value as MyModel;
      print(myModel);
      return value;
    } ,onError: (error) {
     print(error);
      return error;
    },);
  }
```

I have tried everything to solve this issue. May you please guide me what to do. I have even tried with exception handling but still getting this error.

Comment: Is recommended when you assing a Future to a function to also put the expected type that the future will return for example, if the function will return a String, the fuction should be like this `Future<String>` , if will return a Map<String, dynamic>, it should be `Future<Map<String, dynamic>>` , verify what is the function returning and them add it to the future.

Comment: Your code does not demonstrate the error.

Comment: I'm getting this error on runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the Future of return type like `Future<dynamic>`

NetworkApi

```
class NetworkApi {
  NetworkApi(this.url);

  final String url;

  Future<dynamic> getData() async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      String data = response.body;

      return jsonDecode(data);
    } else {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(response.statusCode);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

ApiSelector

```
class ApiSelector {
  Future<MyModel> getApiData({String categoryName = ""}) async {
    late NetworkApi _api;
    if(categoryName != ""){
     _api = NetworkApi('api');
    }else{
      _api = NetworkApi('myapi');
    }
    var Data = await _api.getData();
    if (Data['status'] == 'error') {
      throw'Error while fetching data';
    }
    return MyModel.fromJson(Data);
  }
}
```

MyFunction To Call API selector

```
  Future<MyModel?> getDataFromApi() async {
   try {
     var value = await _apiSelector.getApiData(categoryName: "Some Category");
     myModel = value as MyModel;
     return myModel;

   } catch(error) {
      print(error);
      return error;
   }
  }
```

Comment: Still Same error

Comment: There is one issue in your answer i want to return value dynamic from "Myfunction to call api selector" you have mentioned Future<MyModel>

Comment: Updated my answer, try this again if you can.

Comment: I have solved the issue by myself. Please do check the solution. And thank you so much for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in `getDataFromApi`:

```dart
Future getDataFromApi() async {
    await _apiSelector
        .getApiData(categoryName: "Some Category")
        .then((value) {
      myModel = value as MyModel;
      print(myModel);
      return value;
    } ,onError: (error) {
     print(error);
      return error;
    },);
  }
```

As explained by the error message, your `onError` handler fails to return the same type as returned by `Future.then`'s success path. (See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66397222/ for an explanation.)  This normally would be a compile-time error but ends up being a runtime one because `getDataFromApi` is declared to return a `Future` (equivalent to `Future<dynamic>` instead of `Future<MyModel>`.

Using the raw `Future` API with error callbacks (whether with `Future.then`'s `onError` argument or with `Future.catchError`) is rather confusing to use directly.  You're already using `await`, so there's no reason for you to be using `Future.then`.  With `await`, you can use `try`-`catch` instead, which makes the problem much clearer:

```dart
Future<MyModel> getDataFromApi() async {
  try {  
    var myModel = await _apiSelector.getApiData(categoryName: "Some Category");
    print(myModel);
    return myModel;
  } catch (error) {
    print(error);
    return error; // WRONG: This is not a `MyModel`!
  }
}
```

To fix this, either your `catch` block needs to return a `MyModel` or must throw an exception.

Answer (score -2):

```
class ApiSelector {
  Future getApiData({String categoryName = ""}) async {
    late NetworkApi _api;
    if(categoryName != ""){
     _api = NetworkApi('api');
    }else{
      _api = NetworkApi('myapi');
    }
    var Data = await _api.getData();
    if (Data['status'] == 'error') {

    //I had to replace throw with Future.value Now All Errors are gone.
             return Future.value( 'Error while fetching data');
    }
    return MyModel.fromJson(Data);
  }
}
```

I hope this will also help others who will face this kind of error sometime in future.

Comment: This is the wrong way to fix your problem.  This only "works" because it stops using your broken error path.

Comment: And actually, I'm not sure how this code compiled since `return Future.value('Error...')` isn't compatible with the `Future<MyModel>` return type.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I forgot to remove Future<MyModel>.