# How can "A value of type 'void' can t be returned by the 'onError' handler..." on Future.catchError() be avoided?

Tags: dart

Here's the simple Dart code which works, but generate a compiler warning:

```
Future<String> fetchUserOrder() {
  return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
    throw UnsupportedError('out of coffee');
//    return 'ristretto';
  });
}

void main() {
  print('main: start');

  fetchUserOrder()
      .then((value) {
        print(value);
      })
      .catchError((error) => print(error.message)) // DISPLAYED WARNING: A value of type 'void' can t be returned by the 'onError' handler because it must be assignable to 'FutureOr<Null>'.
      .whenComplete(() => print('complete'));
}
```

How is it possible to avoid the compiler warning "A value of type 'void' can t be returned by the 'onError' handler because it must be assignable to 'FutureOr'." displayed on the catchError line ?

Comment: I accidentally linked to the wrong duplicate and now can't re-close this, but see https://stackoverflow.com/q/66396293/

Comment: I guess your situation is a bit different since your `.then` callback doesn't explicitly return anything.  Still, just use `try`-`catch` and `await`.

Answer (score 2):

The direct way is to use an async function:

```dart
void main() async {
  print('main: start');
  try {
    var value = fetchUserOrder();
    print(value);
  } catch (error) {
    print((error as dynamic).message);
  } finally {
    print('complete'));
  }
}
```

If you want to use `Future` methods instead, you can make the `then` call return a `Future<void>` as:

```dart
void main() {
  print('main: start');

  fetchUserOrder()
      .then<void>((value) {
        print(value);
      })
      .catchError((error) => print(error.message))
      .whenComplete(() => print('complete'));
}
```

I'd probably personally go with including the `catchError` in the `then` call:

```dart
void main() {
  print('main: start');

  fetchUserOrder().then<void>((value) {
    print(value);
  }, onError: (dynamic error) {
    print(error.message);
  }).whenComplete(() => print('complete'));
}
```

Using `then` allows you to set the required return type of the `onError` callback, and it can be used even when there is no value callback, as:

```dart
 someFuture.then<void>((_){}, onError: (e, s) { 
   do something without returning a value;
 });
```