# My future is returning a non-nullable value when I don't think that should be possible

Tags: dart, asynchronous

I wrote [a very small package](https://pub.dev/packages/future_queue) for myself in order to execute futures sequentially, it does the following:

1. Ensures that futures are executed in the order they are "appended", each waiting for the previous future to finish.
2. Passes the last returned result to the next future being executed.
3. Returns the value of the appended future.

Here is the complete code of the package:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

class FutureQueue<T> {
  final Duration? _timeLimit;

  Future<T?> _future;

  FutureQueue({Duration? timeLimit})
      : _timeLimit = timeLimit,
        _future = Future.value();

  FutureQueue.seeded(
    FutureOr<T> seed, {
    Duration? timeLimit,
  })  : _timeLimit = timeLimit,
        _future = Future.value(seed);

  Future<T?> get future => _future;

  /// Adds the given [future] to queue. Note that the [previous] value will be
  /// null if the last operation caused an exception.
  Future<T?> append(FutureOr<T> Function(T? previous) future,
      {Duration? timeLimit}) {
    return _future = _future.catchError((_) {}).then((previous) {
      if (timeLimit != null || _timeLimit != null) {
        return _withTimeout(future(previous), timeLimit ?? _timeLimit!);
      }
      return future(previous);
    });
  }

  Future<T> _withTimeout(FutureOr<T> future, Duration timeLimit) {
    return Future.value(future).timeout(timeLimit);
  }

  /// Waits for queued events to finish.
  Future<void> close() async {
    await _future;
  }
}
```

I've seen this error reported in production when calling append with a Future that returns a non-nullable value and then using the null-check operator to assert that it is not null:

```
_CastError: Null check operator used on a null value
  File "api_token_repo.dart", line 37, in ApiTokenRepo.fetch.<fn>
  File "zone.dart", line 1434, in _rootRunUnary
  File "<asynchronous suspension>"
  File "user_bloc.dart", line 169, in UserBloc._mapUserProfileReloadStarted
  File "<asynchronous suspension>"
  File "user_bloc.dart", line 71, in UserBloc._configureEventHandling.<fn>
  File "<asynchronous suspension>"
  File "bloc.dart", line 211, in Bloc.on.<fn>.handleEvent
```

The code where the exception is thrown is as follows:

```dart
  Future<ApiToken> fetch() {
    return _futureQueue
        .append((_) => _fetchAndSave())
        .then((apiToken) => apiToken!); // <- Exception thrown here
  }

  Future<ApiToken> _fetchAndSave() async {
    final apiToken = await _fetcher();
    _saver(apiToken);
    return apiToken;
  }
```

The exception is thrown when calling `apiToken!` and I can't understand how this is possible. My understanding is that if an exception was thrown when calling `_fetchAndSave` then the `then` call would be bypassed since an error occurred. If an error didn't occur then `_fetchAndSave` doesn't allow a non-null value to be returned.

My first impression was that perhaps it is a race condition where append is called twice and the second call is made before the first finishes and the result of the second is being returned to the first call of append but my (admittedly not great) understanding of how dart code is executed led me to believe that this is not possible. I've tried to simulate such circumstances with tests making hundreds of calls to append with different delays but I've been unable to reproduce such a result.

Note that I am using the timeout functionality of my FutureQueue class if that is helpful.

---

I am aware of alternative packages for making Futures run in a sequence (I'm not sure if any exist with exactly the same functionality) but I would like to fully understand the issue as it makes be doubt my understanding of how Dart is executed.

Comment: I am confused.  How would returning a *non*-nullable value a problem?  Why would you need to assert that a non-nullable value is not null?  Do you actually mean "*nullable*" everywhere you say "non-nullable"?

Comment: And even then, it doesn't seem too surprising that you might end up with a `Future` that resolves to `null`.  After all, `FutureQueue<T>.append` returns a `Future<T?>`, so callers should expect `null`.  It's really hard to reason about your code since you're using [`.catchError`, which can be confusing to use](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66396293/).  I strongly recommend first rewriting your code to use `async`/`await`.

Comment: Thanks for the responses @jamesdlin. I can see how my wording may be confusing, I'll try to clarify. So the `_fetchAndSave` function returns a non-null value and therefore I would expect `append` to return a Future which either resolves to a non-null value or throws an error. Instead the Future returned by `append` is resolving to null and I can't understand how that is possible given the way `append` is written and the fact that I am passing it a Future which can't resolve to null. I want to understand how that is possible for my own understanding  and then to write a failing test and a fix.

Comment: Okay, so the description from your original question is backwards.  You want to know how you got back a *null* value from something you expected be *non*-nullable.  As I stated, that expectation is already wrong since `append` returns a `Future<T?>`: that `Future` resolves to `T?` which can be `null`.  One reason is because your `.catchError` handler returns nothing (and as explained in the linked question, it must return a `Future` of the same type as the original one).  That you don't normally encounter the failure provides supporting evidence that the problem occurs along the failure path.

Comment: I am aware that the return type of `append` allows for a null however I can't see how it can return a Future which resolves to null if you pass it a Future which can't resolve to null.

The `catchError` is called on the previous future not the one being returned.

I'm not disagreeing that the failure path is causing this (it would seem likely to me too) however I've failed in all my attempts to reproduce the exception with tests causing failures.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you must be running in unsound mode (sound null safety is not enabled), and you are having a null leak in through some non-null-safe library.

For instance, where does `_fetcher` come from? Is it delegating to an implementation provided by another library? Possibly that library is giving you a function which returns null in some scenario?

Here is a gist illustrating the situation https://gist.github.com/jakemac53/d95b9fd8aa55d03cf306b6c7b897132d.

Comment: Wow I hadn't considered that and it is completely imaginable that it could cause such an error. I've checked all my dependencies with pub and everything is null safe. I also searched for any opt-outs at the top of files and there don't appear to be any so I don't think that is the cause in this case. Thanks for taking the time even to write an example of how this could be the cause.

Comment: I would try converting append to return a `Future<T>` like this https://gist.github.com/jakemac53/493caff5f1c5b75b713901a5bda2014c.

That should trigger the error earlier (if you have sound null safety enabled).

Comment: I will do that, thanks Jake.