# Invalid argument(s) (onError): The error handler of Future.catchError must return a value of the future's type

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, flutter-future

I am trying to write a dart code program which can register users and sign in users, upon error print its description which i will eventually use in a Toast but it given an error on catchError

```
Future<void> signIn(String email, String password) async {
    if (_form.currentState!.validate()) {
      print(email);
      await _auth
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)
          .then((uid) => {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Login Successfully"),
        Navigator.of(context)
            .pushReplacementNamed(UploadScreen.routeName),
      })
          .catchError((e) {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Incorrect Email or Password.',
            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        );
      });
    }
  }
```

E/flutter ( 7093): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s) (onError): The error handler of Future.catchError must return a value of the future's type
E/flutter ( 7093): #0      _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:193:7)
E/flutter ( 7093): #1      Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:778:47)
E/flutter ( 7093): #2      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:799:13)
E/flutter ( 7093): #3      Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:609:5)
E/flutter ( 7093): #4      _completeOnAsyncError (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:272:13)
E/flutter ( 7093): #5      FirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword (package:firebase_auth/src/firebase_auth.dart)
E/flutter ( 7093): 
E/flutter ( 7093):

Comment: check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66396293/the-return-type-void-isnt-assignable-to-futureort-as-required-by-future

Answer (score 1):

**Consider using try catch instead.**

Try this:

```
Future<void> signIn(String email, String password) async {
    try{
        final User user = (await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email,
          password: password,
        )).user;
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Login Successfully"),
        Navigator.of(context)
          .pushReplacementNamed(UploadScreen.routeName),
      } catch (e) {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Incorrect Email or Password.',
            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        );
      }
  }
```

Comment: I was run my project in my mobile phone. It's work properly. and I think it was the emulator error. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onError function

```
Future<void> signIn(String email, String password) async {
    if (_form.currentState!.validate()) {
      print(email);
      await _auth
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)
          .then((uid) => {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Login Successfully"),
        Navigator.of(context)
            .pushReplacementNamed(UploadScreen.routeName),
      }).onError((e, s) {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Incorrect Email or Password.',
            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        );
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: I was run my project in my mobile phone. It's work properly. and I think it was the emulator error. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Future<dynamic> signIn(String email, String password) async {
    if (_form.currentState!.validate()) {
      print(email);
      await _auth
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)
          .then((uid) => {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Login Successfully"),
        Navigator.of(context)
            .pushNamed(UploadScreen.routeName), //change here 
      })
          .catchError((e) {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Incorrect Email or Password.',
            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        );
      });
    }
  }
```

//Change in the return type make it dynamic