# The return type 'void' isn't a 'FutureOr<List>', as required by the closure's context

Tags: dart

How to process `onError` in the following request? On `print` statement there is an error:  `The return type 'void' isn't a 'FutureOr<List<dynamic>>', as required by the closure's context.`

```
Future<List<dynamic>> _getJson(String url) => HttpClient()
      .getUrl(Uri.parse(url))
      .then((req) => req.close())
      .then((response) => response.transform(utf8.decoder).join())
      .then((jsonString) => json.decode(jsonString) as List<dynamic>).onError((error, stackTrace) => print(error.toString()));
```

Comment: For an explanation for why `Future<T>.onError` and `Future<T>.catchError` need a callback that returns a `T`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66397222/.  I *strongly* suggest that you make your function `async` and use `await` with `try`-`catch` instead of using `.then()` and `.onError`.  Doing that would have made it a lot easier for you to see what you did wrong.

Comment: @jamesdlin I agree that using a code with declarative style a bit easier than in functional style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are experiencing this kind of error, because the method's return type is Future<List>, but inside the onError method you are trying to return the print method, which has a return type of void. In other words the onError method must return a list.
So convert your statement to block body and return an empty list.

```
.onError((error, stackTrace) {
    print(error.toString());
    return [];
}
```