# How to handle errors coming back from Futures when I am not awaiting the Future?

Tags: dart, exception, future

I have something like this:

```
Future<void> f1() { ... }
Future<void> f2() { ... }
Future<void> f3() { ... }

void main() async
{
  f1();
  f2(); // might throw an Exception

  await f3();
}
```

Note - I am deliberately not awaiting f1 or f2, I am only awaiting the consequences in f3.

How do I handle the possibility of an exception in f2 ? The normal try / catch procedure doesn't work.

I have seen some discussion of catchError but I don't really understand it.

I would like to do the equivalent of:

```
Future<void> f1() { ... }
Future<void> f2() { ... }
Future<void> f3() { ... }

void main() async
{
  f1();
  try 
  {
    f2(); // might throw an Exception
  }
  on MyException catch( e )
  {
    print('this is what I expected to happen, so carry on regardless');
  }

  await f3();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, you can use [`Future.catchError`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Future/catchError.html):

```dart
void main() async {
  f1();
  f2().catchError(
    (e) => print('this is what I expected to happen, so carry on regardless'),
    test: (e) => e is MyException,
  );

  await f3();
}
```

Note that [`Future.catchError` can be tricky to use](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66396293/).  You always can wrap your `Future` in another function that internally uses `await` with `try`-`catch`, and then the caller doesn't need to use `await`:

```dart
void main() async {
  f1();

  void ignoreFailure(Future<void> future) async {
    try {
      await future;
    } on MyException catch (e) {
      print('this is what I expected to happen, so carry on regardless');
    }
  }

  ignoreFailure(f2());

  await f3();
}
```

If you don't need to do any handling for the error and want to ignore *all* failures, you also can use the [`ignore` extension method on `Future`s](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/FutureExtensions/ignore.html):

```dart
void main() async {
  f1();
  f2().ignore();

  await f3();
}
```

Comment: Ha ! While the answer above was a perfect answer to my question, it seems that I left some important information out of the original question ! The exception isn't coming from f2 directly, it's coming from a call to scheduleMicrotask inside f2.

Comment: @AdamRose Well that's a different question, not an omitted detail.  You asked for the equivalent of using `try`-`catch` without making the caller use `await`, but that wouldn't work with an exception from `scheduleMicrotask` either.

Comment: You're quite right - I apologise ! I've posted an answer to the real question below. But your excellent answer to the question I posted helped me understand how catchError works. It's only when none of your answers worked in my case that I realised something else was going on

Comment: @AdamRose I mean, if you're asking a different question, you should actually post it as a separate question.  Answering a different question from the one you asked doesn't help anyone searching in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
test('repeated NBA', () async {
  bool fired = false;

  runZonedGuarded( () async {
    Signal s2 = Signal();

    s2.nba( 2 );
    s2.nba( 2 );
    s2.nba( 3 );
  },
  (error, stackTrace) {
    print('Seen expected error: $error');
    fired = true;
  } );

  await Future.delayed( Duration.zero );
  expect( fired , true );
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).